Adding click event to plotLine in Highcharts
I am trying to add a click event to a plot line in Highcharts.
According to the documentation this should be possible. Slightly editing the example from the documentation, it does not work for the band (working of the provided example with a band here, but same outcome for plot lines).


const report = document.getElementById('report');

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
            to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
            events: {
                click: () => {
                    alert('Band click');
                }
            }
        }],
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        point: {
            events: {
              click: function () {
                alert('Series click');
              }
            }
        }
    }]
});
#container {
    height: 300px;
}
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="report"></div>



The click on the series throws the alert as expected.
What am I doing wrong?

This looks like a bug in HIghCharts. You can see in the DOM inspector that the click event is bound to the highcharts-plot-bands-0 element, but the event is not fired because the overlaid .highcharts-plot-border element is not propagating the event. If you remove that element, then the click on the band works

When I tap the band in your edited example I get the alert “band click”.  iOS safari.

Thanks, both. Seems to be an OS specific problem. I just tried it on my phone (iOS) and it works fine, as James pointed out. Thanks for drilling down on the elements, Rory, I will flag to the Highcharts developer community that at least under Windows it bugs.

The issue is due to the pointer-events: fill CSS property applied to the .highcharts-plot-border element which is overlaid on top of the band in the chart.
Override that setting to fix the problem, for example to auto:
.highcharts-plot-border {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

I'd suggest raising this with HighCharts as a potential bug, as you should not have to apply this CSS change for events bound to a PlotBand to be handled.
Here's a full working example with the fix applied:


const report = document.getElementById('report');

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
      color: '#FCFFC5',
      from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
      to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
      events: {
        click: () => {
          alert('Band click');
        }
      }
    }],
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    // one day
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          alert('Series click');
        }
      }
    }
  }]
});
#container {
  height: 300px;
}

.highcharts-plot-border {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="report"></div>




Sorry to bother again, but the fix only works for bands, not for lines and I am not skilled enough to find out which other element is blocking the event. See here f.e. https://jsfiddle.net/xLfqzep4/3/

In case someone comes along this threat at a later stage, posted workaround for plot lines below as an answer.

There's a couple of other elements which are auto-generated which you also need to apply that CSS property to: https://jsfiddle.net/cvy25sw4/

Expanding Rory's correct answer to include the workaround for plot lines as well, one has to add
.highcharts-plot-border {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.highcharts-plot-band {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.highcharts-plot-line {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

to the css file.


const report = document.getElementById('report');

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
            to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4),
            events: {
                click: () => {
                    alert('Band click');
                }
            }
        }],
        plotLines: [{
                    color: 'red', // Color value
                    dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Sty
                    value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),
                    width: 2, // Width of the line    
            events: {
                click: () => {
                    alert('Line click');
                }
            }
            }],
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        point: {
            events: {
              click: function () {
                alert('Series click');
              }
            }
        }
    }]
});
#container {
    height: 300px;
}

.highcharts-plot-border {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.highcharts-plot-band {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.highcharts-plot-line {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="report"></div>



